# WPF View screen offset in Web Browser C#

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, browser, mshtml

I can move to certain location of the page by using:

```
HTMLDocument doc2 = (HTMLDocument)webBrowser1.Document;
int offSetTop = 1000;
doc2.parentWindow.scrollTo(0, offSetTop );
```

The screen automatically scroll to point(0,offSetTop) of the page.
But if I scroll manually to that position of page,
how can I get the offSetTop value if there is no element tag there ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get `offSetTop` ,current position of page with `scrollTop` attribute:try this code

```
   HTMLDocument doc2;
        private void wb_LoadCompleted(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            doc2 = (HTMLDocument)wb.Document;
        }

        private void GetCurrentpositionOfPage_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show( doc2.parentWindow.document.body.getAttribute("scrollTop").ToString());
        }
```

Comment: First, I loaded a html file from my local computer.
After it finished loading, I moved the vertical scroll bar to the middle of the page.
I added GetCurrentpositionOfPage_Click to button click event and  tried. I only got 0 returned. It should be a number that bigger than 0, may be 1xxx, right? 
Did I do something wrong?

Comment: Thank you @irsog, I found the solution. I don't know why but I can get the value by using:
    doc2.documentElement.getAttribute("scrollTop")
Thank you so much